# Informatica Mapping to create Target File of Mainframe File Layout

Tags: information-retrieval, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am looking for suggestions, on how this requirement be approached.
I have to come-up with Informatica mapping to construct below Target File.

Source File

```
Key-1 Key-2 ACCOUNT-1
Key-1 Key-2 ACCOUNT-2
Key-1 Key-2 CC-ACC-1
Key-1 Key-2 CC-ACC-2
Key-1 Key-2 CC-ACC-3
```

For the above input source layout, I need to have one output record based on below Target File.

Basically, I need to group the data based on Key-1 & Key-2 Field & create a record that can have more than one accounts & more than one credit card account details for a customer.

TARGET FILE << MAINFRAME FILE LAYOUT >>

```
 

Key-1   String 10
Key-2   String 10
BANK-CUSTOMER-INFO
    MGR-NAME    STRING 50   — data to be extracted from MGR Table
    MGR-EMAIL   STRING 100  — data to be extracted from MGR-ADDTNL-INFO Table
    MGR-PHNE    STRING 10   — data to be extracted from MGR-ADDTNL-INFO Table
    CUST-NAME   STRING 100  — data to be extracted from Person Table
    CUST-EMAIL  STRING 100  — data to be extracted from Person-Addtnl_info Table
CUST-ACCOUNT-INFO
    BANK-ACCOUNT OCCURS 5 TIMES
        ACC-NO      STRING 10           ( Key Field )
        ACC-TYPE    STRING 10       — data to be extracted from  A Table
        ACC-TRXN-DTLS   OCCURS 10 TIMES
            ACC-TRXN-DATE   DATE 10     — data to be extracted from  X Table
            ACC-TRXN-MODE   STRING 10   — data to be extracted from Y Table
            ACC-TRXN-AMT    STRING 10   — data to be extracted from Z Table
    CREDIT-CARD-ACC OCCURS 5 TIMES
        CC-ACC-NO       STRING 10       ( Key Field )
        CC-ACC-TYPE     STRING 10   — data to be extracted from  B Table
        CC-TRXN-DTLS    OCCURS 10 TIMES
            CC-TRXN-DATE    DATE 10     — data o be extracted from  X1 Table
            CC-TRXN-MODE    STRING 10   — data o be extracted from  Y2 Table
            CC-TRXN-AMT STRING 10   — data o be extracted from  Z2 Table
```

Questions :-

```
How mapping can be accomplished.
Does Informatica supports to have Target Structure as defined above.
Most of my Target Attributes are to be fetched from multiple tables to construct one record, what should be most efficient way to come with Mapping.
Also, I need to denormalise the data as well to get above structure.
```

Comment: You each Key1/Key2 combination can have up to five bank accounts and up to five credit-card accounts (which are not directly related to the bank accounts)? Where is you source data held? What is the significance of the Informatica, and where does the Mainframe come into it?

Comment: Hello Bill. Key1/Key2 are directly related to Bank Accounts. Source data is held in oracle DB, So informatica would like to pull from Oracle DB and prepare the target file like I have mentioned in my question. Mainframe coming into picture here because Target file created by Informatica will be given back to Mainframe for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

The structure you've shown can easily be achieved with an xml target (so long as you're happy to have the target in xml).

One way to do it is to have a source qualifier for each field you want in the target and then to use joiner transformations to denormalise the details across records. The only drawback will be if you only want to extract a few records as this method will pick up all the records in the source tables each time the mapping runs.

Otherwise you'l need a source qualifier override query that denormalizes the incoming records right at the start (could also do this with inline lookups from powercenter 9.1 on which can be configured to return multiple matches but would be fiddly)

Comment: Hello Daniel - Thank you for your suggestions. XML target would have been mich better though.  I shall try out and let you know. Thanks again.